# Escaping from a problem (mark where it's correct)

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

### What's the two-word (12 letters in total) answer to this puzzle?

```
    VCIMB   YUNFS   XHDHU   GRNSW
   (43125) (42531) (21345) (51324)
            

|[][][][][]|[][][][][]|[][][][][]|[][][][][]|
                  
  




   
    OLMVD   MEYIT   SGVUW   XCSAR
   (24135) (42135) (21543) (51342)

                
|[][][][][]|[][][][][]|[][][][][]|[][][][][]|
```

Hint 1:

> Correct *position* only

Comment: Just wanted to say, it's not really a knowledge puzzle but you most likely are going to have to use Google for the final answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is:

> **[HARRY HOUDINI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Houdini)**, the renowned *escape* artist (hence the title) and stunt performer.

How to work this out? First focus on all the numbers:

> If we consider the positions of the five digits to be numbered 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 (from left to right), we should then assign a '1' in the corresponding square bracketed box below if the number in that position equals that position's number (i.e. if a '1' is in position 1, a '2' is in position 2, etc.) and a '0' otherwise. This yields the following (square boxes concatenated into a single string):
>
>   `VCIMB   YUNFS   XHDHU   GRNSW`
>  `(43125) (42531) (21345) (51324)`
>  `[00001] [01000] [00111] [00100]`
>
>   `OLMVD   MEYIT   SGVUW   XCSAR`
>  `(24135) (42135) (21543) (51342)`
>  `[00001] [01001] [00010] [00110]`

We can then...

> Treat these square-bracketed numbers as **binary strings** to produce the numbers:
>
>  [1][8][7][4]
>  and
>  [1][9][2][6]

Now, focus on the letters:

> If we also extract the letters that fall in the same positions within the strings as the matching numbers, we can extract something of use:
>
>  VCIM**B**   Y**U**NFS   XH**DHU**   GR**N**SW
>  OLMV**D**   M**E**YI**T**   SGV**U**W   XC**SA**R
>
>  i.e. **BUDHUN** and **DETUSA**

Putting this all together, we have:

> **1874 BUDHUN** and **1926 DETUSA**. When we interpret 'BUDHUN' as '**Bud**apest, **Hun**gary' and 'DETUSA' as '**Det**roit, **USA**', this looks an awful lot like a *birth date and birthplace* and a *death date and... er... deathplace*.
>
>  In other words, we are likely looking for the 12-letter name of an individual who was born in 1874 in Budapest, Hungary, and died in 1926 in Detroit, USA.
>
>  And possibly the most famous person who fulfils these criteria (and the first hit on a Google search) is **HARRY HOUDINI**, a man whose profession suits the choice of words in the title perfectly!